# Convert table into grouped statistics of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS-SQL, I have a table hasStudied(sid, ccode, grade) (student id, course code, grade) which keeps track of the past courses a student has studied and the grade they've gotten.

As output of my query, I want to return a list of courses, with the percentage of passing (= not 'F') students in the column next to it, in descending order by that percentage, like this:

```
C1 : 85
C3 : 70
C2 : 67
```

etc.

I have currently managed to break them into two separate tables, one containing coursecode and the number of people passing the course, one containing coursecode and the number of people who have read the course.

This is done by two relatively simple statements, but requires me to do a lot of inefficient calculating in java.

Is there any way to make this in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have two entries with the same student under one course, this should do it:

```
SELECT
ccode,
ROUND((passed::numeric(15,2) / taken_course::numeric(15,2)) * 100, 0) AS percentage_passed
FROM(
    SELECT
    ccode,
    sum(CASE WHEN grade > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS passed,
    count(1) AS taken_course
    FROM
    hasStudied
    GROUP BY ccode
    ) foo
ORDER BY ccode
-- since you want to order DESC by values, instead do
-- ORDER BY percentage_passed
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) Your are correct in assuming that a student cannot read the same course several times.

Since I have my grades stored as Strings A-F, I assumed I could switch grade > 2 for grade != 'f'. However even when doing so I did not get this query to execute correctly, I got an error message "type passed is not a defined system type". 

I still do not quite understand how the passed::numeric(15,2) line works, but I will do some reading into the subject :)

Comment: @gogan111 Let me know if it works. If it doesn't - please provide your schema table and some sample data to test the case so that I can make it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the usage of `cte`:

```
create table #temp(StId int, ccode varchar(5), grade varchar(1))
insert into #temp Values (1,'A1','A'),(1,'A1','F'),(2,'A2','B'),(3,'A2','F'),(4,'A2','F'),(4,'A3','F'),(5,'A3','F')

;with cte as (
    select ccode
    from #temp
    group by ccode
)
select cte.ccode,ratioOfPass = cast(sum(case when t.grade <> 'F' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as float) / count(*)
from cte
inner join #temp t on t.ccode = cte.ccode
group by cte.ccode
```

While calculating, use `sum` with `case-when` and do not forget to `cast` the *value of sum* to float.